# How to give path for contatinated file creation into other folder in C++?

Tags: c++, file, path, concatenation

I have a cpp file in the directory : 
    "/home/bidesh/Coding/6 DOF/RotorCraft/test/NearestPoint/6DoF"

In this code I am creating some output that I need to store in the directory
    "/home/bidesh/Coding/6 DOF/RotorCraft/test/NearestPoint/6DoF/Box"

The outputs are text file whose names are concatenated, how can I give path?

Although I tried to look at internet most of the examples are for simple file names but not for the concatenated ones.

```
string base1("Box");
string base2(".txt");
for(int i=0;i<(nx*ny*nz);++i)
{
    ofstream(base1+to_string(i)+base2);
}
```

So obviously the files are created in the same directory. but how can I give path to this code to create my files in some other directory?

Comment: You can concatenate your name to the end of the path. It can also be a relative path if you like.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to put a slash (`/`) between the directory and the filename to form a [relative path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(computing)#Absolute_and_relative_paths).

```
string base1("Box/");
string base2(".txt");
for(int i=0;i<(nx*ny*nz);++i)
{
    ofstream(base1+to_string(i)+base2);
}
```